Do you need to convert all your input numerical variables to categorical if you want to change the target from regression to classification?
Title.
I did some research on the StachExchange/data science/cross validation, etc, and found that "converting numerical variables' numerical regression problem into categorical variables' classification problem could increase the performance", while I agree with the idea, I am still confused about its detail.
Instead of only change the response variable from numerical to categorical, are we supposed to convert the input features as well, that is, change a list of data like [1, 5, 7, 1, 10, ...] to [low, mid, high, low, high, ...]? Or does it even matter? I have a range of features with different distributions. What would be the strategy to decide the number or the scope of the labels?
This question came to me when I tried to apply this trick. I change my response variable to a normally distributed 5-type categorical variables, very low, low, mid, high, very high. However, it turns out this classification model performed slightly worse than the original regression model, or nearly the same at its best.
Obviously, the quickiest answer to this is test it myself, but I am more interested about the reasoning behind, the necessity and scope of such conversion.

Hi Yuuya. Can you mention where you read that binning numerical variables into categorical variables can increase performance? Knowing that may be very useful to give you an answer and address the statements made in the piece you've read, which could be very incorrect. Have you read this other question and its answers? https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/164936

Hi, J-J-J, just finished read the post you provided, it was quite educating. For the statement I mentioned, I was referring to this post: stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278196/  Although, I am still not sure about the scope of the conversion: say I have a almost perfect normally distributed feature, isn't it better to leave it as numerical rather than converting it to categorical, which according to that post's word, would throw away information to predictor?

This question has been answered numerous times on this site.  NEVER categorize an input variable.  The categorizations will have to depend on the level of the other predictors as shown here.  Categorization represents truly bad statistical practice, and it requires you to have more predictors in the model to make up for the information loss due to arbitrary categorization.

Does this answer your question? When should we discretize/bin continuous independent variables/features and when should not?

@User1865345 a little bit, since I am also wondering how to decide the scope or the boundary of each bin.
